# Function to add and delete from JSON object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two categories "A" and "B". On Click any button of category "A" removes the button and must move to category "B", On Click any button of category "B" adds the button to category "A" and must move from category "B".

```
export const LauncherButtons = [
{   
    linked: false,
    type: 'ABC',
    name: 'ReactJs'
},
{   
    linked: false,
    type: 'ABC',
    name: 'VueJS'
},
{   
    linked: true,
    type: 'XYZ',
    name: 'Angular'
},
{   
    linked: true,
    type: 'XYZ',
    name: 'Javascript'
}
];
```

This is what I am rendering for category "A".

```
 { LauncherButtons.map((button,index) => {
                return(
                button.linked === true &&
               <LauncherActionButton 
                text={button.name} 
                onClick = {this.removeAction}/>
                 );
            })}
```

Rendering category "B".

```
{ LauncherButtons.map((button,index) => {
                  return(
                  button.linked !== true &&
                 <LauncherActionButtonAdd 
                  textAdd={button.name} 
                  onClick = {this.addAction}/>
                   );
                })}
```

So basically, when I click on a button of category "A" (True) it should move to category "B" and become false, similarly, when I click on a button of category "B" (False) it should become true and move to category "A".

Comment: What exactly is your category, the `type` key or the `linked` one?

Comment: The linked one.

Comment: So basically you just want to change the value of linked from `true` to `false` and vise versa?

Comment: Yes and move it accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by `move`? Please add more information.

Comment: basically it's doing true false only.

Comment: You should handle the setting of `linked` in your actions then.

Comment: @Sohan, try out my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leftpad-hw1oe

I've laid out two sections, an active and inactive section. By clicking on a button, you move it to the opposite side. I don't know what your `LauncherActionButton` component looks like so consider this like a bare-bones template.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

export const LauncherButtons = [
  {
    linked: false,
    type: "ABC",
    name: "ReactJs"
  },
  {
    linked: false,
    type: "ABC",
    name: "VueJS"
  },
  {
    linked: true,
    type: "XYZ",
    name: "Angular"
  },
  {
    linked: true,
    type: "XYZ",
    name: "Javascript"
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    buttons: LauncherButtons
  };

  createActiveButtons = () => {
    const { buttons } = this.state;
    return buttons
      .filter(button => {
        return button.linked;
      })
      .map(activeButton => {
        return (
          <button onClick={this.handleOnClick} name={activeButton.name}>
            {activeButton.name}
          </button>
        );
      });
  };

  createInactiveButtons = () => {
    const { buttons } = this.state;
    return buttons
      .filter(button => {
        return !button.linked;
      })
      .map(inactiveButton => {
        return (
          <button onClick={this.handleOnClick} name={inactiveButton.name}>
            {inactiveButton.name}
          </button>
        );
      });
  };

  handleOnClick = event => {
    const { buttons } = this.state;
    const { name } = event.target;

    let updatedButtons = buttons.map(button => {
      if (button.name === name) {
        return {
          ...button,
          linked: !button.linked
        };
      } else {
        return button;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      buttons: updatedButtons
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <div style={{ width: "50%", background: "green", height: "300px" }}>
          {this.createActiveButtons()}
        </div>
        <div style={{ width: "50%", background: "red", height: "300px" }}>
          {this.createInactiveButtons()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When using `map` and `filter` you could have just used `reduce`

Comment: If you guys are willing to make an edit, I'd accept, assuming OP has already marked as answer that is. I'm most curious about how you would avoid `.map()`

Comment: @Sohan hello! Whatsup?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Really sorry. This is the link : https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-http-edpqo

Comment: Your solution totally solves my issue. It's just I am not able to hit the onClick.

Comment: @Sohan nice! Let me take a look at your sandbox and see what could be wrong.

Comment: @Sohan I just updated this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hill-i3prc. It should work now. Just need to pass in the event to handler, and name in the elements. If you like it, please consider marking my answer as the solution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195258/discussion-between-sohan-and-christopher-ngo).

Answer (score 0):

What about using the item as a parameter? for example:

```
removeAction(button) {
  // change button however you like
}

// in the render method
{
  LauncherButtons.map((button, index) => {
    return (
      button.linked  &&
      <LauncherActionButton
        text={button.name}
        onClick={() => removeAction(button)}/>
    );
  })
}
```